# How to maintain the session using Struts 2 and Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, session, struts2

I need to know how to maintain session for one form and multiple `input [Name, City, Country]` using Struts2 and finally data will stored to database using Hibernate.

This form have two buttons:

1. `add` (stored to session);
2. `Submit` (stored to database).

First, enter the form details `Name, City and Country` and click add button data will store to `session`.

Second, enter the details for same and now click `add`.

Third, enter same form details but now click submit button  all details (first second & third) will stored to database using Hibernate.

**Got an error, our code is:**

**`Person.java` :**

```
 @Entity
    public class Person {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private int id;
        private String name;
        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
```

**`PersonAction.java`:**

```
public class PersonAction extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware {

      private Person person = new Person();
     // Database base=new Database();

      public Person getPerson() {
        return person;
      }

      public void setPerson(Person person){
        this.person = person;
      }

      private Map<String, Object> session;

      public void setSession(Map<String, Object> session){
        this.session = session;
      }

      public String execute() { //Create persons
        List<Person> personList = (List<Person>) session.get("personList");
        for (Person p : personList)
        Database.saveData(this);
        personList.clear();
        return SUCCESS;
      }

      public String add() { //Add person
        List<Person> personList = (List<Person>) session.get("personList");
        if (personList == null) {
          personList = new ArrayList<Person>();
          session.put("personList", personList);
          System.out.println("Successfully added");
        }
        personList.add(person);
        return SUCCESS;

      }

    }
```

**`Database.java`:**

```
public class Database {
public static int saveData(PersonAction personAction){
        SessionFactory sf=new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session session=sf.openSession();
        Transaction tran=session.beginTransaction();
    int i=(Integer)session.save(personAction);
    tran.commit();
    session.close();
    return i;

    }
}
```

**`struts.xml`:**

```xml
<struts>
    <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="person" class="org.PersonAction">
            <result>/person.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="person" class="org.PersonAction" method="add">
            <result>/person.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

**`index.jsp`:**

```jsp
<s:form action="person">
    <s:textfield label="Enter your name" name="name"/>
    <s:submit value="Add person" method="add"/>
    <s:submit value="Create persons"/>
</s:form>
```

**`person.jsp`:**

```
<body>
<s:property value="#session.name"/>
</body>
```

Comment: why you want  to store in session

Comment: this s my task one form but different data ...if we enter the data 3 times and finally all data will save to database ...       pls help me to solve dis :)

Comment: yes ...im using sessionAware and HttpSession but i dont know how to do dis :(--ty PSR

Comment: are u storing all the names same time or...?

Comment: nope...first i click to add the registration form data to session..its working good..second time i click to add the same registration form data to session now i had only dis data...i dont know how to retrieve the first added data

Comment: why you need both forms data now?you already saved one

Comment: that is my problem..i need all data.. finally stored to database..have any way?

Comment: sorry i dont have any idea

Comment: I don't understand the issue. Do you know how to keep data in the session? Do you know how to use Hibernate? What specifically is the problem?

Comment: no problem thank u for ur command  PSR :)

Comment: Dave NewTon: i added one pic..please check t out  http://www.flickr.com/photos/97204514@N07/8995089703/ ---Thank u Dave:

Comment: PSR: check dis link http://www.flickr.com/photos/97204514@N07/8995089703/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should map the buttons to the method in action. The default [action mapper](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/action-mapper.html) allows to use button names or `method` attribute to specify the method other than used by the form mapping. For example

```
<s:form action="person">
    <s:textfield label="Enter your name" name="person.name"/>
    <s:submit value="Add person" method="add"/>
    <s:submit value="Create persons"/>
</s:form>
```

Now, in the action you implement [`SessionAware`](https://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/interceptor/SessionAware.html)

```
public class PersonAction extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware {

  private Person person = new Person();

  public Person getPerson() {
    return person;
  }

  public setPerson(Person person){
    this.person = person;
  }

  private Map<String, Object> session;

  public setSession(Map<String, Object> session){
    this.session = session;
  }

  public String execute() { //Create persons
    List<Person> personList = (List<Person>) session.get("personList");
    for (Person p : personList)
     getPersonService().save(p); // save to db
    //clear the list
    personList.clear();
    return SUCCESS;
  }

  public String add() { //Add person
    List<Person> personList = (List<Person>) session.get("personList");
    if (personList == null) {
      personList = new ArrayList<Person>();
      session.put("personList", personList);
    }
    personList.add(person);
    return SUCCESS;
     
  }
   
}
```

Now, you have separated logic via methods mapped to a corresponding button. To make working be sure you have [DMI (Dynamic Method Invocation)](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/action-configuration.html#dynamic-method-invocation) turned on (by default is on) and [interceptors](https://struts.apache.org/getting-started/introducing-interceptors.html#IntroducingInterceptors-IntroducingInterceptors) stack `defaultStack` is applied to the action config (by default it's used).

**struts.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
  "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.3//EN"
  "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">

<struts>
  <constant name="struts.devMode" value="false"/>

  <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="person" class="PersonAction">
      <result>/person.jsp</result>
    </action>
  </package>
</struts>
```

`SessionAware` is a interface that your action or base action should implement if you want to use servlet session to put into your objects. More about it [here](https://struts.apache.org/getting-started/http-session.html).

`ActionContext` is a container placeholder for the action invocation, more detailed explanation is [here](https://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/ActionContext.html).

Comment: thank u Roman its very help full to me :) :)...hey what is the difference b/w sessionAware interface and ActionContext?

Comment: hi Roman: i understand the logic but little bit confused to struts.xml   can u show me the struts.xml file for dis code----thank u Roman

Comment: Roman : Got an Error see da update and thank u for replay me :)

Comment: For error you need to post along with code the stacktrace and include the root cause of the error.

Comment: i made some mistakes in this code.. i cant find the solution thats y i posted all the code :(

Comment: You can't have two action configs with the same name in one package. Read carefully this answer to get know why DMI is used.

Comment: Ok, in the JSP you have one form and you place the action name to the `action` attr. You cant't map two actions to the same form. Thus you have to map it on button using DMI to call the action method. The action mapper could help to map the other method of the action when you press the button.

Comment: Sorry yaar..im new to struts.. im lagging to fix t..can u show me the complete code :( its very help full to me..

Comment: Sorry, I don't have complete code :), I didn't write it. I have just posted it, when I was writing this answer. The code you could find following the links mentioned above, examples and tutorials. It can help.