# How to iterate the session in JSP page?

Tags: java, jsp, session, struts2

How to iterate the session and keep the every submit  value in same page till the session end?

```
<html>
<body>
<s:form action="verify">
    <s:textfield name="stuname" label="Enter Username" /><br>
    <s:textfield name="stuage" label="Enter Age" /><br>
    <s:textfield name="stumarks" label="Enter Marks" /><br>
    <s:textfield name="country" label="Enter Country" /><br> 
    <s:submit value="Click" id="submit"  /> 
</s:form>
<s:iterator>
Name:<s:property value="#session.a" /><br>
Age:<s:property value="#session.b" /> <br>
Marks:<s:property value="#session.c" /><br>
Country:<s:property value="#session.d" />
</s:iterator>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you explain more explicitly what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: i have one form ...if submit the form the details will show to jsp..same page again i entered different value many times the value will show same jsp page

Comment: Still don't get what you are trying to achieve; I feel like session may not be involved at all btw... edit your question to make it more clear, instead of using comments

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for iterator.
In your action set the values to session attributes.
In Jsp retrieve them using there name 
e.g.:

```
Name:<s:property value="#session.a" /><br>
Age:<s:property value="#session.b" /> <br>
Marks:<s:property value="#session.c" /><br>
Country:<s:property value="#session.d" />
```

This should do.

**Update 1:**

For displaying all the set of values entered :
1) Create a `POJO` to store all these values (call `Person`).
2) In your action maintain a `arraylist of Person` objects.
3) At every submit create a new person object and add it to person list.
4) In jsp iterate over the person list and display all the values. 
NO Need for session. Avoid using session as much as possible.

Comment: if i entered same form many times i need the all value in same page like follows:  name:moorthy age:24 marks:87 country:india                 name:Agarwal age:28 Marks:199 country:india

Comment: So you want to list all the set of values one by one?

Answer (score 0):

In the JSP and in action you are dealing with objects or an object that is array of objects. It doesn't matter what a structure is used, what does matter that the object has properties such as `Name`, `Age`,  `Marks`, `Country` and they are belong to the one entity name it `Person`.

```
 @Entity
 public class Person {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   private int id;
   private String name;
   public int getId() {
     return id;
   }
   public void setId(int id) {
     this.id = id;
   }
   public String getName() {
     return name;
   }
   public void setName(String name) {
     this.name = name;
   }
   ...
   //other fields
}
```

Now, the session should contain many of such objects, therefore you should create a list and put it into session.

```
public List<Person> getPersonList() {
  List<Person> personList = (List<Person>) session.get("personList");
  if (personList == null) {
    personList = new ArrayList<Person>();
    session.put("personList", personList);
  }
  return personList;
}
```

Then, in the action you should have an object that maps to the form fields, which when submitted saved into session. It is the same `Person` object.

```
private Person person = new Person();
//public getters and setters
```

Now the map the form

```
<s:form action="verify">
  <s:textfield name="person.name" label="Enter Username" /><br>
  <s:textfield name="person.age" label="Enter Age" /><br>
  <s:textfield name="person.marks" label="Enter Marks" /><br>
  <s:textfield name="person.country" label="Enter Country" /><br> 
  <s:submit value="Click" id="submit"  /> 
</s:form>
```

this form will not display values (because the values are mapped to the action property `Person` and it's empty)

How to fill the `personList` I have already explained in the [previous example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17009157/how-to-maintain-the-session-using-struts2-and-hibernate/17013306#17013306).  Now to iterate the values (persons) from it, that is in the session use

```
<s:iterator value="#session.personList">
  Name:<s:property value="name" /><br>
  Age:<s:property value="age" /> <br>
  Marks:<s:property value="marks" /><br>
  Country:<s:property value="country" /><br>
</s:iterator>
```