# Iterating JSON string using Struts2 iterator - getting nothing printed

Tags: java, json, jsp, struts2, ognl

I have created an application in Struts 2 for displaying by iterating a `JSONObject` object taken from Struts2 session by using Struts2 iterator like as shown below

```
<s:iterator var="menu" value="userMenu.get('permissions')">
   <s:property value="menu.name"/>
</s:iterator>
```

but I am getting nothing printed

**Is there any other alternatives if it is not possible by Struts2 iterator?**

my JSON is shown below

```
{
  "id": 10,
  "groupName": "manager",
  "permissions": [
    {
      "id": 18,
      "name": "Group 1",
      "modules": [
        {
          "id": 6,
          "name": "Company 1",
          "groupId": 18,
          "stat": true,
          "moduleGrpName": "Group 1"
        },
        {
          "id": 8,
          "name": "Company 2",
          "groupId": 18,
          "stat": true,
          "moduleGrpName": "Group 1"
        }
      ],
      "stat": "false"
    },
    {
      "id": 19,
      "name": "Group 2",
      "modules": [
        {
          "id": 17,
          "name": "Company 3",
          "groupId": 19,
          "stat": true,
          "moduleGrpName": "Group 2"
        },
        {
          "id": 15,
          "name": "Company 4",
          "groupId": 19,
          "stat": true,
          "moduleGrpName": "Group 2"
        }
      ],
      "stat": "false"
    }
  ]
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
 public String validateLogin() throws Exception 
    {
        TableUser flag=hobjLoginauth.checkUsercredentials(userName, password);
        System.out.println("Flag :"+flag);
        if(flag == null!=true)
        {
            sessionmap.remove("logincheck");
            setSession(sessionmap);
            sessionmap.put("userId", flag.getId());
            sessionmap.put("user",flag.getUsername());
            sessionmap.put("userMenu", new JSONObject(userModulesServicesImpl.getDeSerialized(flag.getGroupId().getPermissions())));
            sessionmap.put("menuGroups",userModulesServicesImpl.getUserModules());
            return SUCCESS;
        }else{
            sessionmap.put("logincheck","1");
            return ERROR;
        }

    }
```

Comment: If it's a *string* then iterating it is (essentially) meaningless. Iterate over a *data structure*, like an array. You'll need to provide more information.

Comment: i made it as a JSONObject, now can we do iteration using <s:iterator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following getter for JSON

```
public Map getUserMenu(){     
  return JSONObject.fromObject(json);
}
```

also you can do the same using Struts2 utility

```
public Map getUserMenu(){
  Map res = null;
  try {
    Object o = JSONUtil.deserialize(json);
    res = (Map)o;
  } catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return res;
}
```

and iterate a map via

```
<s:iterator var="menu" value="userMenu.get('permissions')">
  <s:property value="#menu.name"/>
</s:iterator>
```

Note that using variable of the iterator is not necessary but if used then it accessed from the value stack context using `#`.

Comment: which json library is this

Comment: json-lib-2.3-jdk15.jar

Comment: This library comes with struts2-json-plugin, if you are using this plugin, then it uses that library as a dependency.

Comment: i have upadted my answer , there i am already calling a method  `validateLogin` upon which my view is shown, so how can i use the above said method

Comment: If you want to know how to work with session see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24790578/573032) or [that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17094765/573032) answer and upvote it if helped you.

Comment: can you suggest some solution for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25975679/struts2-inject-not-working-in-jersey-rest-webservices

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61687/discussion-between-alex-man-and-roman-c).