# @Inject not working in Jersey REST webservices in Struts 2

Tags: java, rest, web-services, struts2, jersey

I have created an application for testing the Struts 2 dependency injection (`@Inject`). The injection is working fine in many areas except Jersey REST service class within which I have defined the webservices actions.

I am getting exception like as shown below:

```
Sep 22, 2014 8:48:50 AM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse mapMappableContainerException
SEVERE: The RuntimeException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at usermodules.services.UserModulesServices.userName(UserModulesServices.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
```

Can anyone please tell me some solution for this?

**struts.xml:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
 
<struts>
<bean class="net.viralpatel.struts2.action.MoreServiceImpl" name="services" />

  <constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value="/rest/.*" />
    <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation"
        value="false" />
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />
    <constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources"
        value="ApplicationResources" />
  
 
    <package name="default" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">
        <action name="login"
            class="net.viralpatel.struts2.action.LoginAction">
            <result name="success">Welcome.jsp</result>
            <result name="error">Login.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

**UserModulesServices.java:**

```
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import net.viralpatel.struts2.action.MoreServiceImpl;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.Inject;

@Path("/users")
public class UserModulesServices {
    
    @Inject("services")
    public MoreServiceImpl moreServiceImpl;

    public MoreServiceImpl getMoreServiceImpl() {
        return moreServiceImpl;
    }

    public void setMoreServiceImpl(MoreServiceImpl moreServiceImpl) {
        this.moreServiceImpl = moreServiceImpl;
    }
    
    @GET
    @Path("/name/{i}")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String userName(@PathParam("i") String i) {
        System.out.println("name::::::::" + moreServiceImpl.validate());
        return "{\"name\":\"" + i + "\"}";
    }
}
```

**MoreServiceImpl.java:**

```
package net.viralpatel.struts2.action;

public class MoreServiceImpl implements MoreServices{

    @Override
    public String validate() {
        return "testing";
    }

}
```

Comment: Read the comments to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17244036/1654265). You should not use the internal XWork injection mechanism, it's full of newer stuff out there to achieve the same goal, and better.

Comment: but @Inject is working in all other classes

Comment: Also if you use Scriptlets everywhere, they work. Also if you use Visual Basic 6, it works. But you shouldn't.

Comment: so what you are upto.......are you telling that i should'nt using @Inject in struts2

Comment: @AndreaLigios but i am not using spring, our application is purely struts2

Comment: Your `UserModulesServices` is outside of the S2 context. Why injection there should work?

Comment: @AleksandrM i did'nt get you....

Comment: Struts2 doesn't know about your `UserModulesServices`. Why it should inject there anything? Read about DI in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [official CDI Plugin documentation](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/cdi-plugin.html):

> **Use the right `@Inject`**
>
> Struts 2 and it's core component XWork use it's own internal
>   dependency injection container. Interestingly, you could name it
>   JSR-330's grandma, since it is an early pre-release version of Google
>   Guice once developed by Crazybob Lee - the same Bob Lee that, together
>   with SpringSource's Rod Johnson, lead the JSR-330 specification.
>
> That said, you will find the `@Inject` annotation both as
>   `com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.Inject` and `javax.inject.Inject`. **Don't
>   mix up those two - `javax.inject.Inject` is the one you want to use with
>   your Struts 2 CDI plugin and CDI integration in general**! While you
>   could use Struts' internal annotation as well, the effect may be
>   strange to undefined - so check your imports!

Then instead of  `com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.Inject`
 use the correct one:  `javax.inject.Inject`

Comment: if i use javax.inject.Inject, do i need to do anything other configuration anywhere

Comment: How to set it as ObjectFactory

Comment: Just install the plugin

Answer (score 1):

For this particular question you should provide bean configuration for

```
<bean class="net.viralpatel.struts2.action.UserModulesServices" name="userModulesServices" />
```

The injection will work, but it's for internal use,

> Internally, the framework uses its own dependency injection container that is very similar to Google Guice.

and you should consider the opportunities for other DI frameworks. See [Dependency Injection](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/dependency-injection.html).

Comment: But I had that bean configuration within my struts.xml

Comment: You have configuration for other class. This bean config you should append to your configuration.