# How do configure struts convention plugin with struts-spring plugin with Action class mapped with annotations

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, struts2, struts2-convention-plugin, struts2-spring-plugin

I am trying to configure spring plugin with strut 2 application which is already running with convention plugin, so I am using annotations. I am using ExtJs for my form submission which was initially working well until I introduced the spring plugin, now the the ajax request cannot locate the actions and it's not showing any response in firebug.

**pom.xml**

```
    <!-- struts 2 dependencies -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
    <version>${struts2.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-convention-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${struts2.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-json-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${struts2.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-spring-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${struts2.version}</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Import the CDI API -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-cdi-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${struts2.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
    <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SP1</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- Spring framework -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

**struts.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
    <constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="ApplicationResources" />
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
    <constant name="struts.convention.result.path" value="/content" />
    <constant name="struts.multipart.saveDir" value="/tmp" />
    <constant name="struts.multipart.maxSize" value="4194304" />
    <constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value="/api/.*?" />

</struts>
```

**web.xml**

```
<display-name>Application</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<listener>  
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>  
</listener> 

<servlet>
  <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<context-param>
<param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
<param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
  <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
  <param-value>/api</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
  <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap</listener-class>
</listener>
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">
</beans>
```

**Action Class**

```
@Namespace("/units")
@Result(
    type = "stream",
    params = {
        "inputName", "stream"
    }
)
public class PropertyTypeAction extends BaseAction implements ActionImpl{

    @PersistenceUnit
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;

    @Action(value="add")
    public String add() {
        .......

    }
}
```

**Ajax Request firebug report, XML tab**

```
XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal:{7fc640bd-f293-4956-8cf2-178765cec735} Line Number 1, Column 1:
```

My question is how can I configure struts-spring plugin to work with struts convention plugin with the annotations.

Comment: I needed it because i had GenericDao in which i was injecting Entity manager, but using CDI, it was always null. After searching online, all The solutions provided were implementing the persistence injection using spring..so thats why i wanted to try the spring solution..the actual problem was that struts 2.3.20 has some logging issues with wildfly(doesnt log anything at runtime)..i just downgraded it to 2.3.16.3 and i was able to trace the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are importing both the **struts2-spring-plugin**, and the **struts2-CDI-plugin**.

Don't.

Choose only one of the above plugins, and then configure it properly:

- To use the **CDI plugin**, simply import the JAR with Maven and start annotating the objects you want to be injected with [the (right) @Inject annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25976813/1654265).
- To use the **Spring plugin**, import the JAR, add the `ContextLoaderListener` in web.xml (that you have already set), and specify that you want to [use Spring as objectFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26907334/1654265) in struts.xml, with the constant:

  ```xml
  <constant name="struts.objectFactory" value="spring" />
  ```

**IMHO** the [**CDI plugin** is the better option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28709075/1654265), if you are using Java EE >= 6.