# Create Web Service (SOAP or REST) using Struts2 and hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest, struts2

i have the problem when calling web service using struts 2 and hibernate...

> HTTP Status 500 - Unable to instantiate Action, actions.events.rest.EventController, defined for 'event' in namespace '/'Error creating bean with name 'actions.events.rest.EventController': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [actions.events.rest.EventController]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

this is my source:

EventController :

```
public class EventController extends BaseAction implements ModelDriven<Object> {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String id;
private Object model; 

private static Map<String, Event> map;
{ 
    List<Event> events = services.getEvents();
    for(Event event : events){
        map.put(event.getId() + "", event);
    } 
}

public HttpHeaders index() {
    model = map;
    return new DefaultHttpHeaders("index").disableCaching();
}

public String add(){ 
    services.createEvent("Event1");
    return "SUCCESS";
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(String id) {
    Integer iid = Integer.parseInt(id);
    model = services.getEventById(iid);
    this.id = id;
}

public Object getModel() {
    return model;
}
```

BaseAction:

```
public class BaseAction extends ActionSupport {
// So that spring can inject the business singleton
protected Services services;

public void setServices(Services value) {
    services=value;
}

// For redirect results
protected String redirectUrl;

public String getRedirectUrl() {
    return redirectUrl;
}

public String redirect(String to) {
    redirectUrl = to;
    return "redirect";
}
```

When I debug, I got error in `List<Event> events = services.getEvents();` in `EventController`. What can it be ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The exception is caused by the fact that 
  **you're referencing to the injected bean `services` from within a *static initialization block***:

  ```
  { 
      List<Event> events = services.getEvents();
      for(Event event : events){
          map.put(event.getId() + "", event);
      } 
  }
  ```

  remove it completely, do this kind of things in a `prepare()` method, or in a `@PostConstruct` method, or wherever but leave static blocks alone.

That said, you are following some bad practices:

- you're returning `"SUCCESS"` while it should be `"success"` or `SUCCESS` (that *is* `"success"`)
- you're putting logic in setters, and it's better not
- I'd also suggest to drop ModelDriven, drop Spring at all and [use CDI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28808488/1654265), but this last is my humble opinion. BTW, ensure to [take a look at what I'm talking about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26733141/load-and-cache-application-scoped-data-with-singleton-and-stateless).