# How to assign Struts2 Iterator values to session

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I can able to assign session value to a textfield which is available inside the Iterator. Now i need to edit and reassign the textfield value (which present inside the iterator) to the same session.
After Form submit, I am not able to get the updated value from the formbean through session.

## JSP Code

```
<s:form name="pvcDefinitionForm" method="POST">
    <table>
        <s:iterator value="#session.pvcDefinitionForm.vrflPvcInfoList" var="vrflPvcInfo" status="idx">
            <%  
                int ind = ((IteratorStatus)ActionContext.getContext().get("idx")).getIndex();   
                pageContext.setAttribute("ind",ind);
            %> 

            <tr>
                <td><s:textfield size="28" value="%{#vrflPvcInfo.pvcId}" name="vrflPvcInfo[%{#attr.ind}].pvcId"  
                    disabled="true" indexed="true" /></td> 
                <td><s:textfield size="5" value="%{#vrflPvcInfo.tin1}" name="vrflPvcInfo[%{#attr.ind}].tin1"
                    indexed="true" /></td>
                <td><s:textfield size="5" value="%{#vrflPvcInfo.version1}" name="vrflPvcInfo[%{#attr.ind}].version1"  indexed="true" /></td>
                <td><s:textfield size="5" value="%{#vrflPvcInfo.productGroup1}" name="vrflPvcInfo[%{#attr.ind}].productGroup1"  indexed="true" /></td>
                <td><s:textfield size="5" value="%{#vrflPvcInfo.node1}" name="vrflPvcInfo[%{#attr.ind}].node1"  indexed="true" /></td>
            </tr>
        </s:iterator>
    </table>
    <script language="javascript">
        if ("<%=processingComplete%>" != "true")
        {
            document.writeln('<input type="image" src="images/Finish_Button.gif"  name="nextButton"   accesskey="N" onclick="checksBeforeFinish(this.form);return false;">');
        }

        function checksBeforeFinish(frm) {
            frm.action="<xss:ATTR content='<%=pvcDefinitionForm.getNextMethod()%>' />!<%=pvcDefinitionForm.getNextAction()%>";
            frm.method.value="<xss:ATTR content='<%=pvcDefinitionForm.getNextMethod()%>' />";
            frm.submit();
            return true;
        }
    </script>
</s:form>
```

## Java Code

```
public String pvcDefinitionVrflFinish() throws java.lang.Exception {
    PvcDefinitionForm formBean = (PvcDefinitionForm) session.getAttribute("pvcDefinitionForm");

    List<VRFLPvcInfo> vrflPvcInfoList = new ArrayList<VRFLPvcInfo>();
    vrflPvcInfoList = formBean.getVrflPvcInfoList();

    for (int i=0 ;i<vrflPvcInfoList.size();i++) {
        VRFLPvcInfo vrflPvcInfo = (VRFLPvcInfo) vrflPvcInfoList.get(i);

        System.out.println("pvcId :"+vrflPvcInfo.getPvcId());
        System.out.println("tin1 :"+vrflPvcInfo.getTin1());
        System.out.println("version1 :"+vrflPvcInfo.getVersion1());
        System.out.println("productGroup1 :"+vrflPvcInfo.getProductGroup1());
        System.out.println("node1 :"+vrflPvcInfo.getNode1());

    }

    PvcDefinitionForm formBeanList = getInstance();
    List<VRFLPvcInfo> vrflPvcInfoList1  = new ArrayList<VRFLPvcInfo>();
    vrflPvcInfoList1 = formBeanList.getVrflPvcInfoList();

    for (int i=0 ;i<vrflPvcInfoList1.size();i++) {
        VRFLPvcInfo vrflPvcInfo = (VRFLPvcInfo) vrflPvcInfoList1.get(i);

        System.out.println("pvcId :"+vrflPvcInfo.getPvcId());
        System.out.println("tin1 :"+vrflPvcInfo.getTin1());
        System.out.println("version1 :"+vrflPvcInfo.getVersion1());
        System.out.println("productGroup1 :"+vrflPvcInfo.getProductGroup1());
        System.out.println("node1 :"+vrflPvcInfo.getNode1());

    }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. If you're trying to change a value via a form submission the *session* value won't be changed until you actually change it--what's submitted must be processed first.

Comment: Yes @DaveNewton via form submit we can't change the session value. So my question is any possibility to change a session value from the JSP (I need to assign the textfield value to the session from jsp)?

Comment: No--once the page has rendered on the client you're out of the Java world. The only way to change something in session from a form is via a submit; that's just how web browsers work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17094765/573032