# Method actionInvocation.getInvocationContext().getSession() is not returning anything

Tags: java, spring, netbeans, struts2, interceptor

I'm quite new to Struts2, interceptors and so on... I'm trying now to do a Login page, and trying to protect it with one custom interceptor I made.

The point is that the page index.jsp is redirecting properly to Inicio.jsp, and the form gets in the screen properly, but when I hit the button "submit" (labeled as "Login") it cames to the very same page.

Debugging the situation I realize that the interceptor is taking the request, but the method getSession() from ActionInvocation class is not working, since is not giving anything.
I tried to get step by step and I can see that parameter actionInvocation has some value, and that this method is returning some stuff actionInvocation.getInvocationContext() ... but when I tried to get the session with this kind of line: Map session = actionInvocation.getInvocationContext().getSession();
    nothing is coming.

I've messed with struts.xml file and NetBeans, but I managed to get working (or at least I guess so, but I'm not 100% sure).

I tried several "working examples" I found over internet, I tried to change interceptor, userDAO, UserActionBean, UserAction, InterceptorLogin, session ... a lot of things, and some of them thrown errors (including NPE) but nothing to get any inch of light.

This is the form in the Inicio.jsp page:

```
   <s:form action="validar" method="POST" namespace="/">
```

This is the struts.xml file:

```
   <struts>
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
<package name="/" namespace="/" extends="struts-default" >
    <interceptors>
        <interceptor name="validar" class="InterceptorLogin" />
    </interceptors>
    <action name="validar" class="UserActionBean">
        <interceptor-ref name="validar" />
        <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
        <result name="INPUT">index.jsp</result>
        <result name="SUCCESS">usuarios.jsp</result>
        <result name="ADMIN">admin.jsp</result>
    </action>
    <action name="privado" class="Listado">
        <result name="sucess">listado.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">index.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
</struts>
```

This is InterceptorLogin.java file:

```
   public class InterceptorLogin implements Interceptor {
@Override
public void destroy() {}
@Override
public void init () {}
@Override
public String intercept(ActionInvocation actionInvocation) throws Exception{

System.out.println("Inside intercept method ...");
    Map<String, Object> session = actionInvocation.getInvocationContext().getSession();



System.out.println("ActionInvocation "+actionInvocation);
System.out.println("getInvocationContext "+actionInvocation.getInvocationContext());
System.out.println("The sesion is "+session);


System.out.println("getName "+actionInvocation.getInvocationContext().getName());
System.out.println("getParameters "+actionInvocation.getInvocationContext().getParameters());
System.out.println("getContainer "+actionInvocation.getInvocationContext().getContainer());

System.out.println("User is "+session.get("user"));
    if ("".equals(session.get("user")) || session.get("user")==null) {
System.out.println("Inside invocation's if");
        return "INPUT";
    } else {
        String resultado=actionInvocation.invoke();
System.out.println("After intercept invocation ");
        return resultado;
    }
}
}
```

And finally, here it is the log from Apache where the traces can be read, with the mortal sentence "The sesion is {}" which implies it goes south through the if-else sentence and it is not working any further.

```
12-May-2019 05:21:56.024 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-239] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload Se ha completado la recarga de este Contexto
Inside intercept method ...
ActionInvocation com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation@2de9277b
getInvocationContext com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext@200ba829
The sesion is {}
getName validar
getParameters {user.password=[Ljava.lang.String;@3c3d7b1c, user.username=[Ljava.lang.String;@33801704}
getContainer com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl@57362cf0
User is null
Inside invocation's if
```

As you can see, all other methods are working properly, but the one I want to use is doing weird things.

The expected result is getting the session from the method getSession to be able to continue with the rest of the logic to check if the session exists or not.

Thanks in advance and warm regards,

Magius

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17013306/573032

Answer (score 0):

Yep, I'm kind of stupid. The method getSession() is not returning anything ... because it doesn't have **YET** anything to return.

Session is being fulfilled with the data coming from MySQL database... which is being set in the invoke. The if-else sentence has to come **AFTER** getting the data from DB.

So, correct (or at least working) order is:

1. Form take user and password from the user.
2. Intercept take it and send the values to bean method.
3. Check against DB if exists or not.
4. Return different values depending if exists and the user Type.
5. Intercept evaluate this output and send back to struts.xml file to determine which page will be shown next.

Thanks to those who have checked / read my problem ;-)

Magius